# Swipe left/right event on ViewController and UITextView over it

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a ViewController on which there is a UITextView. On swipe let/right i want to refil UITextView with some other text. Touch Events are attached on ViewController. Problem is to pass touch events to ViewController i need to setUserInteractionEnabled to NO. but i set it to No then my UITextView does not scroll content.

What shld i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this blog post here : http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

It's for UIWebView but should work right for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)